# Save more then 7 days backup for Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

In the following link https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq it says:
`MySQL Second Generation instances: The most recent 7 automated backups, and all on-demand backups, are retained. They are charged at the backup storage rate. Binary logs use storage space (not backup space), and are charged as storage.`

Is it possible to have save a longer period of automated backups? (without doing it manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups), no. Either take on-demand backups and delete them at your desired retention, or export data to flat file.

Answer (score 0):

They have updated their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#automated-backups) and it is now possible.

> You can configure how many automated backups to retain, from one to 365.

See the [documentation for how to set it](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backing-up#set-retention).

Regarding transaction logs, which are used for point-in-time recovery, unfortunately it seems the maximum number of backups is 7 days worth.

> Transaction log retention is in days and can be set from one to seven.